# Generate payment link and sms invoice using Zoho Books API

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

My application needs me to send a payment link to the customer via SMS. Once the payment is done, capture it and create a paid invoice and again send it via SMS to the customer. But I observed

1. There is no API to generate a payment link
2. Invoice cannot be sent via SMS.

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There IS payment link API, it's just not documented.

If you POST something like

```
{
    "customer_id": 123456000001234567,
    "payment_amount": "1.00",
    "expiry_time": "2022-04-30",
    "description": "TEST"
}
```

to `https://books.zoho.[eu]/api/v3/paymentlinks?organization_id=123456`

you will get a new payment link with default contact email and status "generated". You can get URL from the `response->payment_link->url`.

Unfortunately, I didn't find out how to change the status of the payment link.

You can also send an email with POST to `/api/v3/paymentlinks/{paymentlink_id}/email?organization_id=123456` if you specify subject, body and to_mail_ids array, and also do changes with PUT to i.e. expiry_time, but it would be great to know how to mark payments.